# Trying to build a ReactNative iOS app and getting errors on Macbook Pro with M1 Apple Chip

Tags: react-native

I'm able to successfully run the starter "AwesomeProject" react-native app on both iOS and Android.

I have a private repo project that was built by an outsourced team that I'm trying to get running on my local Macbook Pro with an M1 Chip.  The team claims they are able to get the project running on a normal Macbook Pro (without the M1 chip).

I'm unable to build the project on iOS and get the following error:

> The following build commands failed:  SwiftEmitModule normal arm64
> Emitting\ module\ for\ Charts (in target 'Charts' from project 'Pods')
> (1 failure)

When I try to run the Android app I'm able to get it to run on the Android Device simulator but get the following errors from

> ERROR  Error: token is not a valid string
> ERROR  Invariant
> Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module
> (calling runApplication). A frequent cause of the error is that the
> application entry file path is incorrect.
> This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native.
> ERROR
> Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable
> module (calling runApplication). A frequent cause of the error is that
> the application entry file path is incorrect.
> This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native.

I'm not sure how to further debug these issues.  I followed some of the debugging I saw with M1 Macbooks and React-Native like using "brew" to install cocoapods and then always using "alias pod='arch -x86_64 pod'" for the pod command.  I see lots of other hacks to make react-native work on M1 like this article: https://goxotech.medium.com/apple-m1-react-native-was-not-exactly-what-we-thought-but-that-is-not-an-issue-6c8d359926df

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding this in your PodFile

```
post_install do |installer_representation|
installer_representation.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH'] = 'NO'
        config.build_settings['BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION'] = 'YES'
    end
end
```